# Can any one Explain this behaviour in char array

Tags: java, arrays, char

Please find the code snippet.

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    char[] tmpArray = new char[10];
    tmpArray[0] = 'a';
    tmpArray[1] = 'b';
    tmpArray[3] = 'd';

    for (char element : tmpArray) {
        System.out.print(element);
    }
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(tmpArray));
}
```

I was excepting the `abd` would display .
 but it is not displaying anything in forloop and it is displaying just `"ab"` in sop .

while i try to debug, array still holds the 4th element as 'd'. if if give d in 3rd element it is displaying properly. is it in contract per spec ?. 
 It basically creates new String instance using `Arrays.copy` of the char. even the new char[] (`value` in String instance contain the 'd' as 4th element) . Is this behavior due to  iterating in array while displaying...

 there is no real use case. i just tried to solve other SO question ( irrelevant to this)  and got this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

Comments describing, they are seeing the 'd' at the end. that is what i excepted. but i didnt showed in my machine.

Ubuntu 12, Jdk 1.8 , eclipse kepler. is it releated to eclipse console then ?

Comment: When I ran it, my output was: 'abd'

Comment: [This works perfectly on ideone](http://ideone.com/AIFaLb) (I added `-->` and `<--` markers for clarity).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight. Thank you. thats what i excepted. then it should be problem with eclipse console ( ubuntu)

Comment: I thought , i missing some thing related to char [] / iteration used in String. but later i came to know it is problem with eclipse and ubuntu. as per comments it is working fine in other environments. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming the array will default to a space (' ') character if you do not explicitly set it.  Instead it defaults to null. See

[Can we assume default array values in Java? for example, assume that an int array is set to all zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893663/can-we-assume-default-array-values-in-java-for-example-assume-that-an-int-arra)

Comment: No, My question is not about ' ' between the b and d. my question is i am not seeing 'd' at all

Comment: Oh Ok.  My reply is addressing that you said you expected "ab d",  Which is not what is expected in this case.