# NullPointerException while reading from text and storing it to array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting a nullpointer exception in the following code. The code reads from a text and store eachline in an array. The array is a class which contains a single String array of length 5. I'm getting confused why i'm getting this error.

```
Question[] questions = new Question[100];
File file = new File("q.txt");
    String[] tempq = new String[5];
    try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file);

        while(counter<100){
            for(int i= 0;i<5;i++){
                tempq[i]=read.nextLine();
            }
            questions[counter].setDetails(tempq);
            counter++;

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: And where exactly are you getting the null-pointer?

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
Question[] questions = new Question[100];
```

This line will create an array of 100 `Question` objects, but it won't create each object within the array. Add

```
questions[counter] = new Question();
```

(or whatever your constructor) is to create the question, then set the details.

Comment: I didn't get it what you said exactly

Comment: Your `Question` objects are null. You need to create them. You only have an array.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution, but got java.util.NoSuchElementException error

Comment: A `java.util.NoSuchElementException` is probably coming from your `Scanner` - check that your input file is correct.

Comment: my input files are correct, when i try to do the same thing instead of an arrray, this works

Comment: What do you mean when you try to do the same thing instead of an array? Are you not using an array anymore as per your original code?

Comment: I tried to remove the array and test it for only one Question variable with proper initialization, the code then works, I don't know why. can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Array is by default initialized with default values such as 0 for int, `\u0000` for char `null` for object.

You have to populate the values in array before using it.

For complete list have a look at [Can we assume default array values in Java? for example, assume that an int array is set to all zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893663/can-we-assume-default-array-values-in-java-for-example-assume-that-an-int-arra)