# Use MATLAB cameraParams in OpenCV program

Tags: matlab, opencv, matlab-cvst, calibration

I have a MATLAB program that loads two images and returns two camera matrices and a cameraParams object with distortion coefficients, etc. I would now like to use this exact configuration to undistort points and so on, in an OpenCV program that triangulates points given their 2D locations in two different videos.

```
function [cameraMatrix1, cameraMatrix2, cameraParams] = setupCameraCalibration(leftImageFile, rightImageFile, squareSize)
% Auto-generated by cameraCalibrator app on 20-Feb-2015
```

The thing is, the output of undistortPoints is different in MATLAB and OpenCV even though both use the same arguments.

As an example:

```
>> undistortPoints([485, 502], defaultCameraParams)
ans = 485   502
```

In Java, the following test mimics the above (it passes).

```
public void testUnDistortPoints() {
    Mat srcMat = new Mat(2, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Mat dstMat = new Mat(2, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    srcMat.put(0, 0, new float[] { 485, 502 } );

    MatOfPoint2f src = new MatOfPoint2f(srcMat);
    MatOfPoint2f dst = new MatOfPoint2f(dstMat);

    Mat defaultCameraMatrix = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
    Mat defaultDistCoefficientMatrix = new Mat(1, 4, CvType.CV_32F);

    Imgproc.undistortPoints(
            src,
            dst,
            defaultCameraMatrix,
            defaultDistCoefficientMatrix
    );

    System.out.println(dst.dump());

    assertEquals(dst.get(0, 0)[0], 485d);
    assertEquals(dst.get(0, 0)[1], 502d);
}
```

However, say I change the first distortion coefficient (k1). In MATLAB:

```
changedDist = cameraParameters('RadialDistortion', [2 0 0])
>> undistortPoints([485, 502], changedDist)
ans = 4.8756    5.0465
```

In Java:

```
public void testUnDistortPointsChangedDistortion() {
    Mat srcMat = new Mat(2, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Mat dstMat = new Mat(2, 1, CvType.CV_32FC2);
    srcMat.put(0, 0, new float[] { 485, 502 } );

    MatOfPoint2f src = new MatOfPoint2f(srcMat);
    MatOfPoint2f dst = new MatOfPoint2f(dstMat);

    Mat defaultCameraMatrix = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_32F);
    Mat distCoefficientMatrix = new Mat(1, 4, CvType.CV_32F);
    distCoefficientMatrix.put(0, 0, 2f); // updated

    Imgproc.undistortPoints(
            src,
            dst,
            defaultCameraMatrix,
            distCoefficientMatrix
    );

    System.out.println(dst.dump());

    assertEquals(4.8756, dst.get(0, 0)[0]);
    assertEquals(5.0465, dst.get(0, 0)[1]);
}
```

It fails with the following output:

```
[0.0004977131, 0.0005151587]

junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :4.8756
Actual   :4.977131029590964E-4
```

Why are the results different? I thought Java's distortion coefficient matrix includes both the radial and tangential distortion coefficients.

Also, is CV_64FC1 a good choice of type for the camera / distortion coefficient matrices?

I was trying to test the effect of changing the camera matrix itself (i.e. the value of f_x), but it's not possible to set the 'IntrinsicMatrix' parameter when using cameraparams, so I want to solve the distortion matrix problem first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with javas openCV implementation, but make sure your input points are in the right format: "src – Observed point coordinates, 1xN or Nx1 2-channel (CV_32FC2 or CV_64FC2)." Are they 2 channel?

Comment: What Matlab version are you using btw?

Comment: And wich is your image centre, or image size?

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri, I have somehow skipped the type requirement in the comments! Being used to languages automatically casting types as requested by calling functions, it's a bit difficult to get used to OpenCV's strictness.


I have changed src and desc to be a MatOfPoint2f, accepting a CV_32FC2 type Mat in their constructors. Again, the first test passes and the second one fails.

I am using Matlab R2014b. And there's no image here, this is undistortPoints, not undistort, so it operates on points, not images :)

Comment: Mmmm but it has to operate on images. The equation of the distorsion is based on a image size, having a parameter `r`,  that is the distance from the point to the center. A difference between the two can be due to that parameter. Check wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a couple of things you have to take into account when working with calibration models.

First, note there exist several camera calibration and distortion models: [Tsai](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/DIAS1/), [ATAN, Pinhole, Ocam](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/wiki/Camera-Calibration). I assume you want to use the Pinhole model, which is the used by OpenCV and the most common one. It models from 2 to 6 parameters for radial distortion (denoted as `k1`...`k6`) and 2 for tangential distortion (denoted as `p1`, `p2`), as you can read in the [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html). [Bouget's calibration toolbox](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/bouguetj/calib_doc/) for Matlab uses this model too.

Second, there is not a standardized way to arrange distortion parameters in a vector. OpenCV expects items in this order: `[k1 k2 p1 p2 k3...k6]`, being `k3...k6` optional.

So, check the documentation of your Matlab calibration software and look for what model it uses and in which order the parameters are arranged. Then, make sure it meets the order in OpenCV.

The calibration parameters for OpenCV are ok as `CV_32F` and `CV_64F` as I recall.

**Update**

I don't know in Java, but in C++, when you create a `Mat`, its initial values are unspecified, so that this code may be creating a matrix with a `2f` in the first item and garbage in the remaining ones:

```
Mat distCoefficientMatrix = new Mat(1, 4, CvType.CV_32F);
distCoefficientMatrix.put(0, 0, 2f);
```

Could you check if this is the problem?

A note for the future, to make things trickier, take into account that the intrinsic calibration matrix in OpenCV is the transpose of the one in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks ChronoTrigger, I've checked the function arguments yesterday, and I think they're used correctly. By default, Matlab's [radial distortion](https://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html#input_argument_namevalue_radialdistortion) coefficients are (0, 0, 0) and the [tangential distortion](https://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameraparameters-class.html#input_argument_namevalue_tangentialdistortion) ones are (0, 0). So if I set the first element of distCoeffs array in OpenCV to 2, I update just k1.

Comment: I've looked into it, and the "setupCameraCalibration" function (as mentioned in the first code block in my original question) is the output of [MATLAB's CameraCalibratorApp](https://se.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/cameracalibrator-app.html). The link didn't explicitly mention the camera model used, however that function contains a call to "estimateCameraParameters", whose documentation says "The calibration algorithm assumes a pinhole camera model".

Comment: Thanks for the update! I think the syntax is correct, though. What distCoeff.put(0, 0, 2) does is put the value 2 at the 0th row and 0th column (meaning, the very first value of the matrix is 2), which is the same as [2, 0, 0] in Matlab :)

And yeah, the actual application uses an intrinsic matrix that is definitely not the identity one, and I perform the transpose on it. Thanks for the suggestion though, that's easy to miss as well.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the syntax of `distCoeff.put`, you are right. I removed that part of my answer and updated it again with other idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am aware of both of these points, however. I do the transpose of the intrinsic matrices when I load the data from a text file. As for garbage values, I don't think it's an issue in Java really, as arrays are automatically filled with values depending on the type of primitive (0.0d for doubles, 0 for ints, false for booleans, etc). This answer has more information http://stackoverflow.com/a/3893700/1974160 I might have to try and find an implementation of undistortPoints in any other language and port it if this does not work :(